# Why is the child View's touch area still touchable even if it extends beyond the parent View's?

Tags: react-native

The official documentation says:

> The touch area never extends past the parent view bounds and the Z-index of sibling views always takes precedence if a touch hits two overlapping views.

I interpreted the meaning of this sentence as follows.

"The touch area of ​​the lower view cannot be larger than the size of the upper view."

However, when I ran the following code, I got different results than expected.

The yellow view's touch area is set to be larger than the green view's size, but touching beyond the green view's bounds still works.

```
...
export default function App() {
  const [txt, setTxt] = useState(false);
  const PR = PanResponder.create({
    onStartShouldSetPanResponder: () => true,
    onPanResponderStart: () => {
      // ... start
      setTxt((prev) => (prev ? false : true));
    },
  });

  return (
    <View style={styles.container1}>
      <View style={styles.container2}>
        <View
          style={styles.container3}
          {...PR.panHandlers}
          hitSlop={{ top: 80, bottom: 80 }}
        >
          <Text style={styles.Text}>{txt ? "true" : "false"}</Text>
        </View>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container1: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "red",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
  },
  container2: {
    // flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "green",
    height: 140,
    width: 240,
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
  },
  container3: {
    backgroundColor: "yellow",
    height: 60,
    width: 160,
  },
  Text: {
    fontSize: 36,
  },
});
```

Did I misunderstand the sentence in the official documentation?
please answer me.

Thanks in advance.